# Calculus 1 - Find the area of shaded region

Tags: calculus, area

[image]

I have been working at this for like 3 hours and can find nothing online like it and there are no examples in the text book. I must be missing a simple step somewhere.

The correct answer is given as $$\frac{3 \pi \sqrt 2}{2}$$ but I cannot figure out how it was obtained.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What steps did you take? What did you try? It may be useful to note that $3\sec\theta \tan\theta$ is an odd function.

Comment: What is it that you are having trouble with?  What integral have you set up?  What are your calculations?  We can't help you if we don't know where you are making your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint $\#1$:** *(calculus way)*

The area you are trying to find is between the graphs

$$f(x) = 3 \sqrt 2 \qquad g(x) = 3 \sec x \tan x$$

on the interval $(-\pi/4,  \pi/4)$.

(I don't know why they expressed the latter function in terms of $\theta$, but whatever.)

The area is then given by

$$\text{shaded area} = \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \Big( f(x) - g(x) \Big) \, dx$$

(In case the thing regarding $\theta$ in lieu of $x$ seems potentially an issue, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-pi%2F4+to+pi%2F4+of+%283+sqrt+2+-+3+sec+x+tan+x%29+dx) does happen to give the correct answer, if you just note that $\sqrt 2/2 = 1/\sqrt 2$.)

---

**Hint $\#2$:** *(geometric way)*

You should be able to convince yourself that the blue area makes up half of the area of the rectangle the picture defines:

[image]

(The side lengths of this rectangle are $\pi/2$ and $6 \sqrt 2$.) So if you can somehow convince yourself that the blue area is half, you can avoid calculus altogether!

(This can be somewhat justified by noticing that $y(x) = 3 \sec x \tan x$ is an odd function, i.e. $y(-x) = -y(x)$, and we are over an interval symmetric about zero.)

Comment: Regarding hint #1, the antiderivative of $\sec\theta\tan\theta$ happens to be pretty nice.